# How to return string value in JavaScript Revealing Module pattern

Tags: javascript, string, design-patterns, module

I'm using the Revealing Module pattern in one of my apps and I'm having trouble getting it to return the value of a string variable after the init method is called on the object. The goal is to set the value of stringVar and retrieve it from my UI. arrayVar works.

Thanks,
Chris

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = null;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        viewModel = new ViewModel();
        viewModel.init();
        // writes "object1" to ul
        $("#log").append("<li>" + viewModel.arrayVar[0] + "</li>");
        // writes "" to ul
        $("#log").append("<li>" + viewModel.stringVar + "</li>");
    });

    ViewModel = (function () {
        var
            arrayVar = new Array(),
            stringVar = '',
            init = function () {
                // load data from external source
                arrayVar.push("object1");
                arrayVar.push("object2");
                stringVar = "string value 1";
            };
        return {
            arrayVar: arrayVar,
            stringVar: stringVar,
            init: init
        };
    });

</script>
```

Comment: It's because `stringVar` in the return statement is not a reference, but a copy (a new string).

Comment: Why does it work with arrayVar?

Comment: arrayVar is an array, so it's a reference, not a value

Comment: From my interpretation of RMP, you dont instantiate an RMP.  Your ViewModel is more of a class than a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that strings are immutable, so when you reassign `stringVar` in `init`, it's actually replacing the variable with a new string, leaving the object returned from the constructor pointing to the original.

The simplest way to get around this would be to use a getter function in place of direct access.  If you want property-like access, there are a few options.  There's `__defineGetter__`, which is deprecated, then the ECMA5 getters, which will have limited compatibility:

```
// your constructor
function() {
  // ...

  var getStr = function() {
    return stringVar;
  };

  // saving the returned object to a variable, as a few of the options
  // involve operating on an object.
  var m = {
    // typical getter function
    getStr: getStr,

    // ecma5 pretty syntax getter property
    get str1() { return getStr() }
  };

  // __defineGetter__ variant
  m.__defineGetter__("str2", getStr);

  // ecma5 Object.defineProperty variant
  Object.defineProperty(m, "str3", {get: getStr, enumerable: true});

  return m;
}

// access them like:
viewModel.getStr();
viewModel.str1;
viewModel.str2;
viewModle.str3;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I thought but my brain was thrown for a loop because I thought all of the variables are variant and there would be no difference between them. The problem with using a getter is that I don't want to call the external datasource more than once and I'm trying to figure out how to persist the response in the object so I can access it through the properties. Any ideas?

Comment: Using the getter doesn't mean that you'd have to load the external resource again.  You can leave it exactly as is, except instead of returning the variable `stringVar`, you return a function that returns the `stringVar` local to the constructor.  That way you can replace it in `init` and return the new value.

Answer (score 0):

"this" works. pun intended :)

```
init = function () {
    // load data from external source
    this.arrayVar.push("object1");
    this.arrayVar.push("object2");
    this.stringVar = "string value 1";
};
```

Comment: It's my understanding that one of the major benefits of the revealing module pattern is that you don't have to use 'this' to scope your variables. The example works without adding 'this' to arrayVar but does not work for stringVar. I think there is some subtly I'm missing. Thanks.